How Are Absence Days Counted for Permanent Residence or Citizenship Applications in EU Countries?
When applying for permanent residence or citizenship, EU countries often limit the number of days you can spend outside the country during the qualifying period. However, it’s not always clear how short trips are counted. Below are my specific questions regarding how “absence days” are calculated:
1. Same-Day Trips:
If I leave the country and return on the same day, does this day count as an absence?
2. One-Night Absence:
If I leave on January 1 and return on January 2, would this count as an absence day? If it counts, two days absent? However, since I am physically present in the country on both January 1 and January 2, does this mean no absence is counted?
3. Two-Night Absence:
If I leave on January 1 and return on January 3, how would the absence be calculated? Would it count as one day of absence (January 2 only), two days (January 1–2), or three days (January 1–3)?
General Rule Clarification:
Do countries typically count “full days” absent (midnight to midnight), or do they include departure and return days in the absence calculation? Is there any official source?
Would keeping detailed records of travel dates help ensure compliance with these rules? Are there official guidelines or resources that clearly explain how to track and calculate absence days?
Thank you for any insights or guidance you can provide!

Given the way you phrased the first sentence, it seems you already know this but there really isn't any EU-wide rule. It would therefore be better to ask about a specific country.

True, my texts sound like I wanted an answer of a pan-EU-wide rule, which is not completely what I meant, but I couldn't find any answers about how “absence days” are defined. Is the day of leaving and the day of returning counting as absence or not? I can only find some rules about the UK, which state they don’t count short trips less than two days as absence.

There is no reason to assume that all countries have a definition of “absence days” or even need one.

Also, I see you're asking some question along these lines every two years or so but what's your actual situation? Ultimately, it's not that complicated: whether in Belgium, France, or Germany, you're supposed to actually live in the country, work and build a life there. The system is not too friendly to remote work or people who do not work and certainly not intended to let you roam around Europe while pretending to live in a place. For most working people, the question of how long you have been abroad doesn't even arise, the rules are broad enough to not even come close to the limit…

Once you understand that, you can try to game the system and you might even get away with it but it's easy to see why the rules are not intended to make that easy.

It's difficult to generalize but based on what I know about a handful of European countries, I would say that this way to approach the problem is unlikely to help you. The law is really designed to prioritize people who live and work in a place, the more you depart from that norm, the weaker your case will be.
In France, the requirements vary depending on the exact procedure but are generally phrased as “X years of uninterrupted residence”. There is no time threshold, what matters is intent and what case law calls “the center of your interests” and family life. For example, if you worked and stayed in France for 5 years but your kids and spouse live abroad, it can be grounds to consider that you do not fulfill the residence requirement and postpone your naturalization, even if you personally spent very little time abroad.
In Germany, the requirements are typically phrased as a number of months of residence and contribution to the welfare state (which implies being physically in Germany to work). Residence permit can also become invalid after 6 months abroad (with some exceptions and nuances). The Netherlands also has similar rules. No specific threshold or requirement for naturalization itself but you need to have maintained your main residence in the Netherlands. This residence can be deemed to have been interrupted if you stayed more than 6 months abroad or if you stayed at least 4 months abroad without interruption during 3 years in a row.
In all these cases, intent matters and the rules are expressed in years or months. You won't find more specific official guidance and that's by design. Whenever there is a threshold, it's to define a length of stay abroad that leads to automatic disqualification, not a rule that guarantees that shorter stays are necessarily OK. So if you need to count the days to argue your case, you are already on shaky grounds and will find it difficult to convince a court to step in.

Thanks for your reply. I understand your concerns, and I understand the rule varies by countries. What I would like to ask was how “absence days” are calculated. Is the day of leaving and the day of returning counting as absence or not? Thanks again if you could shine some ideas.

@EricC What I am explaining is that this question doesn't even make sense for most countries. It's not how your application will be evaluated.
